# Laravel | Unique validation where clause

Tags: mysql, laravel, api, lumen

I am trying to validate the input of a email address that exists but only when the company_id is the same as the company_id which is passed in with the request.

I am getting this error...

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '1' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from company_users where email_address = myemail.com and 1 <> company_id)

I have read online and the way to do it is to associate the table and the column inside of the validation which is what I am doing.

This is my current code...

```
required|email|unique:company_users,email_address,company_id,' . $request->company_id
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here is a rough idea with this you can achieve what you

You can use `Rule` class to customize the validation rule for you.

```
'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:191',Rule::unique('users')->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
    return $query->where('company_id', $request->company_id);
})],
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That seemed to work for the email being unique, but then how do I chain on the required + email validation I had on before?

Comment: @tallent123 you can use separtely   'email' => 'required' and then this

Comment: states there is a duplicate array key if I do this

Comment: @tallent123  You can pass closure and array of validations too. Let me update he answer

Comment: i get this now `Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateRequired|email does not exist.`

Comment: @tallent123 which version you are using?

Comment: I'm using `Lumen (5.6.1) (Laravel Components 5.6.*)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166595/discussion-between-laravel-levaral-and-tallent123).

Comment: Rule::unique('App\Models\User') add your table name like Model.  https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Validation/Rule.html#method_unique

Answer (score 8):

This should answer your question.

```
'required|email|unique:company_users,email_address,NULL,id,company_id,' . $request->company_id
```

This means, the email must be **unique** while ignoring a row with an `id` of `NULL` and where its `company_id` is the same as `$request->company_id`.

The **except** parameter ignores rows to compare against the validation. E.g., an email address of `abc@gmail.com` has already been taken by user `1` but you did this:

```
'unique:company_users,email_address,1'
```

It will ignore user with `id` of 1. So inputting the same email will still pass since the ***existing*** user with the same email has been ignored.

Which is not the same in your case, because you just dont want to ignore a special row, but you want to ignore a row based on a condition. So that is how this answer helps you, by adding more field validations **after** the ***ignore*** parameter.

You might want to take a look at this: [laravel 4: validation unique (database) multiple where clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377069/laravel-4-validation-unique-database-multiple-where-clauses)

Comment: awesome, simple and works!

Answer (score 7):

It has to be like:

```
required|email|unique:company_users,email_address,' . $request->company_id
```

The format is:

```
unique:table,column,'id to exclude'
```

Or if you want to validate based on a column you can do a separate query:

```
$exists = Model::where('company_id','!=',$request->company_id)->where('email',$request->email)->count()
if($exists) {
  // return an error or a validation error
}
```

Comment: How does it know what it is the company_id I am wishing to exclude though?

Comment: Even if I change the id of the company it says it's already being taken. Seems like that's doing a global search the email?

Comment: it knows that the `ID` belongs to the table given in the rule in your case its `company_users` , so what it does it selects all the email from that table and excludes the row that has the ID equals to what u wanted to exclude then it counts how many rows

Comment: The structure is `| id | company_id | email_address | password |` this doesn;'t seem to work

Comment: are those the columns of the `company_users`?

Comment: they are the columns yeah

Comment: okay I guess I got what you want to do, you're not making it based on the ID but rather on the `company_id` which is not a primary key, to make it work you should use a query rather than a rule, I will edit my question to show u how

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use same method inside the `FormRequest` class for the request, then you can use it as follows,

```
'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:191', Rule::unique('users')->where(function ($query) {
    return $query->where('company_id', $this->company_id);
})],
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `$request->company_id` a string by adding `'` single quotes around your variable. Otherwise MySQL will think is a column in your table.

```
required|email|unique:company_users,email_address,company_id,"'" . (int) $request->company_id . "'"
```

Comment: `Unknown column '`6`' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `company_users` where `email_address` = email@email.com and ```6``` <> company_id`