# Laravel unique validation of two columns when validating against an array

Tags: laravel, validation

I can validate two table columns for uniqueness by customizing the where query like this.

```
'email' => [
    'required',
    Rule::unique('users')->where(function ($query) {
        return $query->where('account_id', $this->request('account_id'));
    })
]
```

How would i do a similar thing when validating an array of data?

```
'email.*' => [
    'required',
    Rule::unique('users')->where(function ($query) {
        // How can i customize the query per array element?
    })
]
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19377725/6212294) may help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**2022 Update**

Laravel 9 now has functionality for this exact problem.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#accessing-nested-array-data

---

Ended up with the following, though i was hoping there was a way to access the current index of the currently validated array element from within the function params themself.

```
$i = 0;

'email.*' => [
    'required',
    Rule::unique('users')->where(function ($query) use (&$i) {
        return $query->where('account_id', $this->request('account_id')[$i]);
        $i += 1;
    })
]
```